# How to make paramiko SSH server execute cammands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to write an SSH server and everything is fine but the problem seems that I cant make client to execute commands on the server as normal and can't find correct way to do it since there is no mention of it in the documentation and can't see a demo example of how to make server to accept connections so I'm completely lost in this area. code is:

```py
#!/bin/python3
import paramiko
import socket    

class Ctx(paramiko.server.ServerInterface):
    
    def get_allowed_auths(self, username):  return "password,publickey"
    def check_auth_publickey(self, key):    return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
    def check_channel_request(self, kind, channelID): return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
    def check_channel_shell_request(self, channel):  return True
    def check_channel_pty_request(self, c, t, w, h, p, ph, m): return True
    def get_banner(self):         return ("This is MY SSH Server\n\r", "EN")

    def check_channel_exec_request(self, channel, command):
        print(command)      # Print command 
        self.event.set()    # I dont know why this is used.
        return True         # return True to accept command exec request

    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if password == "1999":    return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        else:                     return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

paramiko.util.log_to_file("demo_server.log")    # setup log file
host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename="./rsa")    # setup rsa key file that will be used during authnitication
ctx = Ctx()                                     # create ServerInterface context object
sock = socket.socket()                          # Create socket object
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5555))              # bind socket to specific Port
sock.listen(100)                            # Listen for TCP connections
print("***************** Listening for connection **************************")
client, addr = sock.accept()                # accept TCP socket connection
print("[+]*****************  Listeing for SSH connections ***************** ")
server = paramiko.Transport(client)
server.add_server_key(host_key)             # Setup key
server.start_server(server=ctx)             # SSH start_server
channel = server.accept(30)                 # Accept Auth requests
if channel is None:
    print("[+] *****************  No Auth request Was made. ***************** ")
    exit(1)
channel.send("[+]*****************  Welcome ***************** \n\r")
while True:                                 # This is supposed to be used to listen to commands
    channel.event.wait(5)                   # but I'm not sure what it does actually
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer is fine for executing a single command. This new version supports the following variations:

1. `ssh ip-address -p 5555 -T` - Creates an interactive session. For now each input line is just echoed back and logged until 'quit\n' is entered.
2. `ssh ip-address -p 5555 some-command` - Executes the single command `some-command`, but for now that consists of just echoing back the command and logging it.
3. `ssh ip-address -p 5555 exit` - shuts down the server if `SUPPORT_EXIT = True` is set in the source.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import socket
import sys
import threading
from queue import Queue

import paramiko

logging.basicConfig()
paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo_server.log', level='INFO')
logger = paramiko.util.get_logger("paramiko")

host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename='./rsa')

SUPPORT_EXIT = True

# input queue of requests:
in_q = Queue()

def my_processor(stdin, stdout, event):
    stdout.write('This is MY SSH Server:\n\n')
    for command in stdin:
        if command == 'quit\n':
            break
        # Just log the command and send it back:
        logger.info('Command = %s', command)
        stdout.write(command)
    # signal termination
    event.set()

class Server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind == 'session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED

    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if password == '9999':
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

    def get_allowed_auths(self, username):
        return 'publickey,password'

    def check_channel_exec_request(self, channel, command):
        # This is the command we need to parse
        command = command.decode() # convert to string from bytes:
        if SUPPORT_EXIT and command == 'exit':
            # Place None in in_q to signify time to exit:
            in_q.put(None)
        # We just log it and echo it back to the user:
        logger.info('Command = %s', command)
        channel.send(command + '\n')
        self.event.set() # Command execution complete
        # Show command successfully "wired up" to stdin, stdout and stderr:
        # Return False if invalid command:
        return True

    def check_channel_shell_request(self, channel):
        """ No command specified, interactive session implied """
        stdout = channel.makefile('w')
        stdin = channel.makefile('r')
        threading.Thread(target=my_processor, args=(stdin, stdout, self.event), daemon=True).start()
        # Show command successfully "wired up" to stdin, stdout and stderr:
        return True


def run_server(client):
    t = paramiko.Transport(client)
    t.set_gss_host(socket.getfqdn(""))
    t.load_server_moduli()
    t.add_server_key(host_key)
    server = Server()
    t.start_server(server=server)
    # wait for termination:
    server.event.wait()
    t.close()


def accept(sock):
    while True:
        try:
            client, _ = sock.accept()
        except Exception as exc:
            logger.error(exc)
        else:
            in_q.put(client)


def listener():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', 5555))

    sock.listen(100)

    threading.Thread(target=accept, args=(sock,), daemon=True).start()

    while True:
        try:
            client = in_q.get()
            if SUPPORT_EXIT and client is None: # exit command issued
                break
            threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(client,), daemon=True).start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

Comment: I just tested this version which is the most complete version now I only have to execute the command. Thanks a lot.  I marked this answer as accepted answer.

Comment: And now you have unaccepted it. Is there a problem?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the output of your `print` statement in `check_channel_exec_request`, you are receiving a command name. You just need to execute the command and send the output to the client. One implementation of that might look like:

```
def check_channel_exec_request(self, channel, command):
    try:
        res = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        channel.send(res.stdout)
        channel.send_exit_status(res.returncode)
    except Exception as err:
        print('exception: {}'.format(err))
        channel.send('An error occurred: {}\r\n'.format(err))
        channel.send_exit_status(255)
    finally:
        self.event.set()
    return True
```

This uses `subprocess.run(...)` to execute the command and then sends
the output to the client. There are several limitations to this
implementation...

- It's not interactive (the output isn't returned to the client until
  *after* the command is complete).
- It doesn't handle command output on *stderr*

...but hopefully it's enough to get you started.

---

Another problem with your code is with your treatment of
`client.event`. This is a Python [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) object, used for signaling between threads. When you write:

```
channel.event.wait(5)
```

You are saying "wait up to 5 seconds for the Event to be set". An
Event becomes set by something calling `event.set()`, which you can
see we are doing in `check_channel_exec_request`.

The way you're using this doesn't make sense, by writing:

```
while true:
  channel.event.wait(5)
```

You have an infinite loop. You want something that will wait for the
command to execute and then close the channel, so maybe something
like:

```
channel.event.wait(30)
channel.close()
```

This means "wait up to 30 seconds for the command to complete, and
even if it doesn't, close the channel".

With these two changes, your code will accept a single command and
exit. If you want the server to keep running so that you can connect
to it multiple times, you will need to implement some sort of loop in
the main section of your code.

Here's the code with all the changes I suggested:

```
#!/bin/python3
import paramiko
import socket
import subprocess
import time


class Ctx(paramiko.server.ServerInterface):
    def get_allowed_auths(self, username):
        return "password,publickey"

    def check_auth_publickey(self, key):
        return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL

    def check_channel_request(self, kind, channelID):
        return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED

    def check_channel_shell_request(self, channel):
        return True

    def check_channel_pty_request(self, c, t, w, h, p, ph, m):
        return True

    def get_banner(self):
        return ("This is MY SSH Server\n\r", "EN")

    def check_channel_exec_request(self, channel, command):
        try:
            res = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            channel.send(res.stdout)
            channel.send_exit_status(res.returncode)
        except Exception as err:
            print('exception: {}'.format(err))
            channel.send('An error occurred: {}\r\n'.format(err))
            channel.send_exit_status(255)
        finally:
            self.event.set()
        return True

    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if password == "1999":    return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        else:                     return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED


paramiko.util.log_to_file("demo_server.log")  # setup log file
host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(
    filename="./test_rsa.key"
)  # setup rsa key file that will be used during authnitication
ctx = Ctx()  # create ServerInterface context object
sock = socket.socket()  # Create socket object
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5555))  # bind socket to specific Port
sock.listen(100)  # Listen for TCP connections

print("***************** Listening for connection **************************")
client, addr = sock.accept()  # accept TCP socket connection
print("[+]*****************  Listening for SSH connections ***************** ")
server = paramiko.Transport(client)
server.add_server_key(host_key)  # Setup key
server.start_server(server=ctx)  # SSH start_server
channel = server.accept(30)  # Accept Auth requests
if channel is None:
    print("[+] *****************  No Auth request Was made. ***************** ")
    exit(1)
channel.send("[+]*****************  Welcome ***************** \n\r")

# wait for command execution to complete (or timeout)
channel.event.wait(30)  # but I'm not sure what it does actually
channel.close()
```

---

### Update 1

Just to be clear, this doesn't get you an interactive session. This lets you run a command like this:

```
$ ssh -p 5555 localhost date
This is MY SSH Server
lars@localhost's password:
[+]*****************  Welcome *****************
Sun Aug 15 09:35:53 AM EDT 2021
Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
```

If you want to enable an interactive session, `check_channel_exec_request` is not what you want.

> does this mean that I have to open a new channel for each command, Is this is how it's supposed to be done with SSH or I can just use the wait in loop so that only one channel for all upcoming commands.

Using *this* model, with `check_channel_exec_request`, you would need a new connection for each command. The main section of your code would look like:

```
while True:
    print("***************** Listening for connection **************************")
    client, addr = sock.accept()  # accept TCP socket connection
    print("[+]*****************  Listening for SSH connections ***************** ")
    server = paramiko.Transport(client)
    [...]
```

This isn't the only way of handling things, of course, and if you look
around you can find a number of examples of Paramiko-based services
that might help out. For example, [ShuSSH](https://github.com/kryptographik/ShuSSH) shows a non-trivial Paramiko server implementation.

Comment: thanks a lot this answer is very informative so I'm up voting this answer. but I have a question does this mean that  I have to open a new channel for each command, Is this is how it's supposed to be done with SSH or I can just use the wait in loop so that only one channel for all upcoming commands.

Comment: also when running ```ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 5555 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no``` i'm stuck at ```welcome ``` without being able to send commands and recieve back it's output.

Comment: See the updates I've made to the question.

Comment: thanks a lot got it now. Now i know where I should start I must see how to use paramiko to get an interactive session.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already did an "early acceptance" of an answer, but you might take a look at the following, which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837898/python-integration-testing-using-paramiko-to-fake-a-ssh-server-and-log-the-co) on SO that has been modified as follows:

1. Uses threading to support concurrent SSH requests.
2. Recognizes an "exit" command to terminate the program since the code to handle ctrl-C for termination is less than ideal. Set constant `SUPPORT_EXIT = False` to remove this support.

The program just currently logs the command and echoes it back to the user.

Example of use:

```
ssh localhost -p 5555 some-command
```

The code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import socket
import sys
import threading
from queue import Queue

import paramiko

logging.basicConfig()
paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo_server.log', level='INFO')
logger = paramiko.util.get_logger("paramiko")

host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename='./rsa')

SUPPORT_EXIT = True

# input queue of requests:
in_q = Queue()

class Server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind == 'session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED

    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if password == '9999':
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

    def get_allowed_auths(self, username):
        return 'publickey,password'

    def check_channel_exec_request(self, channel, command):
        # This is the command we need to parse
        # Here we just log it and echo it back to the user:
        command = command.decode() # convert to string from bytes:
        logger.info('Command = %s', command)
        channel.send(command + '\n')
        if SUPPORT_EXIT and command == 'exit':
            # Place None in in_q to signify time to exit:
            in_q.put(None)
        self.event.set()
        return True


def run_server(client):
    t = paramiko.Transport(client)
    t.set_gss_host(socket.getfqdn(""))
    t.load_server_moduli()
    t.add_server_key(host_key)
    server = Server()
    t.start_server(server=server)

    # Wait 30 seconds for a command
    server.event.wait(30)
    t.close()


def accept(sock):
    while True:
        try:
            client, _ = sock.accept()
        except Exception as exc:
            logger.error(exc)
        else:
            in_q.put(client)


def listener():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', 5555))

    sock.listen(100)

    threading.Thread(target=accept, args=(sock,), daemon=True).start()

    while True:
        try:
            client = in_q.get()
            if SUPPORT_EXIT and client is None: # exit command issued
                break
            threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(client,), daemon=True).start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

Comment: yea although non of the answers show how can I make this server act like ssh servers available for public but I guess this is my problem since I don't really understand how the protocol really works. I thought that these libraries will just take care of the interactive session turns out that they just provide basic minimum and you will have to use them to build a fully interactive session which is still a mystery for me, but I guess maybe this is for another question.

Comment: When I have a chance I will look into this further.